# PlaceAutocompleteAdapter not resolved but it already has a class

Tags: javascript, java, android, google-maps, search

in my Google Map project PlaceAutocompleteAdapter for searching places cannot be resolved but it already has a class.

Codes are below:
Gradles will be at the bottom.

**MapActivity Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(-40, -168), new LatLng(71, 136));

    //widgets
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //vars

    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mPlaceAutoCompleteAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mSearchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

        getLocationPermission();

        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: Initializing");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();


        mPlaceAutoCompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);

        mSearchText.setAdapter(mPlaceAutoCompleteAdapter);

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        ||  keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "GeoLocate: found a Location: " +address.toString());

           //Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT()).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the device's current location.");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){

                final com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Found Location");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                                moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                        DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                        "My Location");

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current Location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " +latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));

        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);

            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();

    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            initMap();

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted.");
                    //initializing map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }



}
```

**PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter Class**

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 *
 *  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 *  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 *  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 *  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 *  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 *  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 *  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 *  limitations under the License.
 */


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.GeoDataClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.RuntimeExecutionException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

/**
 * Adapter that handles Autocomplete requests from the Places Geo Data Client.
 * {@link AutocompletePrediction} results from the API are frozen and stored directly in this
 * adapter. (See {@link AutocompletePrediction#freeze()}.)
 */
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutocompleteAdapter";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    /**
     * Current results returned by this adapter.
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;

    /**
     * Handles autocomplete requests.
     */
    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;

    /**
     * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
     */
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;

    /**
     * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
     */
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    /**
     * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)
     */
    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GeoDataClient geoDataClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1);
        mGeoDataClient = geoDataClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
     */
    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
        // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
        // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(item.getPrimaryText(STYLE_BOLD));
        textView2.setText(item.getSecondaryText(STYLE_BOLD));

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

                // We need a separate list to store the results, since
                // this is run asynchronously.
                ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> filterData = new ArrayList<>();

                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    filterData = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                }

                results.values = filterData;
                if (filterData != null) {
                    results.count = filterData.size();
                } else {
                    results.count = 0;
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    mResultList = (ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction>) results.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getFullText(null);
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
     * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
     * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
     * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
     * successfully.
     * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
     * from the API, which may include a network request.
     *
     * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
     * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
     * @see GeoDataClient#getAutocompletePredictions(String, LatLngBounds, AutocompleteFilter)
     * @see AutocompletePrediction#freeze()
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

        // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
        // contain the results when the query completes.
        Task<AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse> results =
                mGeoDataClient.getAutocompletePredictions(constraint.toString(), mBounds,
                        mPlaceFilter);

        // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most
        // 60s for a result from the API.
        try {
            Tasks.await(results, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | TimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            AutocompletePredictionBufferResponse autocompletePredictions = results.getResult();

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
            return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
        } catch (RuntimeExecutionException e) {
            // If the query did not complete successfully return null
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Gradle for Module: app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5+'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

    //Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

By the way, thanks to those who will answer. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you defining that class? It has no package name. You also haven't imported it in your Activity.

Comment: What do you mean by not imported in my activity? Sorry, im not good in programming.

Comment: You need to import classes when they're not in the same package as the current class. See all the `import` lines?

Comment: Is there a tutorial for that? Thanks though. Btw, I’n really not an IT student, i’m just a digital arts students that was given an app by our panel head

Comment: To import classes? Look up basic Java tutorials, or click the red class-name, hit `Alt`+`Enter` (`Alt` --> `Cmd` for macOS) and select the import option in the context menu.

Comment: I’m doing that, but when its prompting me to create another class but its already existing

Comment: where does it already exist? There's no package line in what you pasted.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. The one popping up is " already contains class named "PlaceAutoCompleteAdapter" whenever 'Alt + Enter'